# Создать и добавить файл в gitlab ci пайплайне

Tags: python, gitlab, gitlab-ci, непрерывная-интеграция, allure

Помогите с настойкой CI пайплайна:
Суть в том что после прохождения тестов в `after_script:` нужно добавить создание файла `environment.properties` записать в него evn=$EVN и положить в папку `allure-results`

```
run_tests:
    stage: test
    image: python
    artifacts:
        when: always
        expire_in: 5 days
        paths:
            - allure-report
    before_script:
        - pip install -r requirements.txt
    script:
        - pytest -v --alluredir=allure-results
    after_script:
        - Тут нужно создать файл environment.properties записать в него evn=$EVN и положить в папку allure-results
        - allure generate -c allure-results -o allure-report
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- touch allure-results/environment.properties
- echo "URL=$BASE_URL" > allure-results/environment.properties
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]